# In Django, How do I get escaped html in HttpResponse?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, escaping, httpresponse

The following code in one of my views returns unescaped html string which cannot be parsed in frontend since it is an Ajax request.

```
return render_to_response(template_name, {
        'form': form,
        redirect_field_name: redirect_to,
        'site': current_site,
        'site_name': current_site.name,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

What is the simplest way to correct this ?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 37):

**Lakshman Prasad**'s answer is technically correct, but a bit cumbersome. A better way to *escape* text would be (as suggested in a comment by **miku** above):

```
from django.utils.html import escape
return HttpResponse(escape(some_string))
```

Comment: docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.escape

Answer (score 6):

To return just plain HTML to the client from within your view, use `django.http.HttpResponse`

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def view(request)
    # Do stuff here
    output = '''
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Hey mum!</title>
        </head>
    </html>'''
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

To prevent the Django templating system from escaping HTML in a template, just use the `|safe` filter:

```
response = "<img src='cats.png'/>"

# Meanwhile, in the template...
<div id="response">
    {{response|safe}}
</div>
```

Comment: Django is not autoescaping the response which I have confirmed using firebug.
I need it to be escaped.

Comment: So, you want `<p>` to change to `&lt;p&gt;`?, or stay as `<p>`?

Answer (score 1):

It should escape by default.

But, if you want to, you can explicitly force escaping.

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_for_escaping
return HttpResponse(mark_for_escaping(loader.render_to_string(""""Render Response Syntax"""))
```

Answer (score 0):

For escaping `html` you can use `escape` module.

And also you can override this behavior of `HttpResponse` by:

```py
from django.utils.html import escape
from django.http import HttpResponse

class HttpResponseEscaped(HttpResponse):
    def __init__(self, content, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(escape(content), *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score -1):

In Django, auto-escaping is off by default

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It is not OFF by default, it's ON.