# How to break line on html when use string from python

Tags: python, html, css, line, newline

Basically I'm building a chatbot using **python**. When running on python, I can display the answer with multiple lines by using **`\n`** tag. However , when I bring it to HTML to display it on website using Flask, it cannot render **`\n`** tag so there is no line break.

I have also tried to replace **`\n`** to  `<br/>` but no help. It prints out the **br** tag instead of converting it to a line break.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

in some textArea  `<br/>` will not word
you can use `&#10;` to brekline
just like use `&nbsp;` to stand for  space in html

Comment: I also tried , but it also print out `&#10;` instead

Answer (score 0):

You could try to pass `&lt;br&gt;` It's the escaped `<br>` Tag [Link](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-escape.html#ad-output)

Comment: still cannot do it . it still print out the text

Comment: Maybe this helps you. [Link](https://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingHtml) you need to escape the code

Comment: If this doesn't help, there is another similar question but with django in use [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946281/in-django-how-do-i-get-escaped-html-in-httpresponse)

Comment: Its still not working . I tried all the ways but no help. Thanks for your help anw.

Answer (score 0):

Try using these options. 
If your content-type is html, then use
`"String to be displayed"+"<br \>"+"The string to be displayed in new line"`
Else, If your content-type is plain text then use
`"String to be displayed"+"\n"+"The string to be displayed in new line"`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Despite i used Django for my website i suppose the logic and syntax are the same.

You can do it through the variable and adding "|safe" in your html code.

For example, in your python code you have:

```
broken_string = "first line<br>second line"
```

and

```
return render_template('index.html', html_broken_string = broken_string)
```

And in your HTML code you should have:

```
{{ html_broken_string|safe }}
```

That should do the work.

P.S: I don't remember if you can actually pass string directly in your render_tamplate() function and omit creation of a new variable in Flask, so i didn't write that. But you can try.